# How to get a browser url for a Gmail thread from the threadId parameter in Gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Threads in Gmail API have a `threadId` that looks like an hex number: **1784d63938119544**.

I want to build a url for the same thread that you can use in your browser, but there, the suffix looks different https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/**FMfcgGzsmDlfgdRfJFk**
as if base64-encoded or similar.

Do you know how these are related?